# Multiple Fusioncharts is not getting displayed in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, fusioncharts

I'm using **FusionCharts** on iOS. I'm having problems in loading multiple **UIWebView** with fusion charts. The problem is that only one webview shows correctly the chart. The second one loads and renders the chart but only shows correctly after I **scroll** the view.

The charts are rendered properly only after scrolling the view. What could be causing this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: is the charts looks crushed at the load

Answer (score 0):

The problem this issue is is with UIWebView it self for clear explanation check out below link
http://double-slash.net/2010/10/18/using-multiple-ios-uiwebview-objects/ It can be fixed in two way by adopting a spin lock mechanism or increasing rendering time of run loop by customize the UIWebview.

```
@interface FCXTCustomWebView ()

@property (assign) id idelegate;

@end

@implementation FCXTCustomWebView

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    self.delegate = self;
}

return self;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self)
{
    self.delegate = self;
}

return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.delegate = self;
}
return self;
}

- (void)setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)delegate
{
_idelegate = delegate;
}

- (void)stopRunLoop
{
CFRunLoopRef runLoop = [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] getCFRunLoop];
CFRunLoopStop(runLoop);
}

- (void) webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
[self performSelector:@selector(stopRunLoop) withObject:nil afterDelay:.01];

if ([_idelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webView:didFailLoadWithError:)])
{
    [_idelegate webView:webView didFailLoadWithError:error];
}
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
if ([_idelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)])
{
    return [_idelegate webView:webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}
else
{
    return YES;
}
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[self performSelector:@selector(stopRunLoop) withObject:nil afterDelay:.01];

if ([_idelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webViewDidFinishLoad:)])
{
    [_idelegate webViewDidFinishLoad:webView];
}
}

- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[self performSelector:@selector(stopRunLoop) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
if ([_idelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(stopRunLoop)])
{
    [_idelegate webViewDidStartLoad:webView];
}
}

- (void) loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
{
[super loadHTMLString:string baseURL:baseURL];
CFRunLoopRunInMode((CFStringRef)NSDefaultRunLoopMode, 1.5, NO);
}

@end
```